# Why does calcium carbonate decompose in sulphuric acid?

Tags: ionic-compounds, decomposition

Here's the reaction:

$\ce{H2SO4(aq) +  CaCO3(s)  ->   CaSO4(s)  + H2O(l)  +   CO2(g)}$

I don't understand why calcium carbonate decomposes in sulphuric acid. It's not soluble in water. I could understand the hydrogen ions oxidizing the calcium, yet the reaction isn't a redox reaction; the oxidation states remain the same!

Comment: Very related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/47049/why-does-caco3-react-with-hcl-but-not-with-h2so4/47050#47050

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't understand why calcium carbonate decomposes... It's not soluble in water.

It's more soluble in water than you might think.  If it weren't soluble, we wouldn't have awesome things such as [stalagmites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalagmite) in caves.

Calcium sulfate is more soluble in water than the carbonate, but that isn't saying much.  It's solubility is only about $\pu{2 g/L}$. So writing the product as $\ce{CaSO4(s)}$ is only correct if you are talking about dilute solutions.  Anything too concentrated would decompose to form precipitated calcium sulfate.

> I could understand the hydrogen ions oxidizing the calcium...

Now *that* would be a very curious reaction.  The calcium in calcium carbonate is already in the +2 oxidation state. Calcium has only two valence electrons and further oxidation would require disrupting an intact octet.  It would be very unfavorable.  $\ce{Ca^{2+} -> Ca^{3+} + e-}$ would be far too unfavorable a reaction for protons to carry out. $\ce{Ca^{3+}}$ would be a much stronger oxidant than aqueous protons.

> Why does calcium carbonate decompose in sulphuric acid?

The decomposition can still happen even with insoluble, solid-phase calcium carbonate because reactions can happen at surfaces. An acidic proton could be attacked by a solid-phase carbonate ion at the crystal surface, forming bicarbonate.  The bicarbonate could attack another acidic proton, forming a surface-bound $\ce{H2CO3}$ molecule, which could spontaneously transform into $\ce{CO2}$ and water, which would be very loosely bound to the surface, allowing them to escape and exposing fresh not-yet-reacted calcium carbonate molecules to the aqueous surface, and the process begins anew...

Answer (score 0):

Since carbon dioxide is released out, leading to decrease  in concentration of product ,hence the reaction goes in forward direction to attain equilibrium leading to breakdown of calcium carbonate.